# Merging custom CodeDOM reference

Tags: dll, reference, merge, codedom, ilmerge

I need a way of merging my custom DLL with my CodeDOM output automatically when it's build. I think about using ILMerge, but, it's there a better way?

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid ILMerge?

Comment: I'm not really trying to avoid it, but just asking if there's a better way of doing it...